# UNION Query Error - "You have tried to execute a query that does not inlude the specified expression..."

Tags: sql, ms-access, union

I am trying to combine multiple queries via UNION.  When I try to execute, I get the following error:

"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'DateRec' as part of the aggregate function."

Any ideas?

Here is my Query.

```
SELECT [Leads Received by Agent].DateRec, [Leads Received by Agent].AgentID, 
    [Leads Received by Agent].AgentFirstName, [Leads Received by Agent].AgentLastName, 
    Count([Leads Received by Agent].LastAction) AS CountOfLastAction, 
    'Leads Received by Agent' as type 
FROM [Leads Received by Agent]

UNION ALL

SELECT [Leads Proposed by Agent].DateRec, [Leads Proposed by Agent].AgentID, 
    [Leads Proposed by Agent].AgentFirstName, [Leads Proposed by Agent].AgentLastName, 
    Count([Leads Proposed by Agent].LastAction) AS NumofLeadsProp, 
    'Leads Proposed by Agent' 
FROM [Leads Proposed by Agent]

ORDER BY [Leads Received by Agent].DateRec;
```

Comment: you need to group by daterec, agentid, agentfirstname, agentlastname AND TYPE if you want a count of actions. in both unions.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY on columns which dont have a aggregate function on both selects.

Answer (score 2):

Add a group by clause as follows to each half of the union, for example...

```
SELECT [Leads Received by Agent].DateRec, 
       [Leads Received by Agent].AgentID, 
       [Leads Received by Agent].AgentFirstName, 
       [Leads Received by Agent].AgentLastName, 
       Count([Leads Received by Agent].LastAction) AS CountOfLastAction, 
       'Leads Received by Agent' as type 
FROM [Leads Received by Agent]
GROUP BY [Leads Received by Agent].DateRec, 
         [Leads Received by Agent].AgentID, 
         [Leads Received by Agent].AgentFirstName, 
         [Leads Received by Agent].AgentLastName,'Leads Received by Agent' as type
```

Also, I don't suggest "type" as a column alias as it [is a reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286335/en-us).